# Problem managing accented chars with Flask on Linux

Tags: python, flask, url, utf-8

I'm using Flask 2.2.2 under Linux; Flask is operating in the back of WSGI. I'm testing my code under Windows with the Flask embedded server.
I'm using url like this one
`http://joconde.givingsense.eu/onto/debug/champlitte_;_musée_départemental_albert_demard`

the code
`uri = flaskrequest.url`
gives me
`http://joconde.givingsense.eu/onto/debug/champlitte_%3B_mus%25c3%25a9e_d%25c3%25a9partemental_albert_demard`

an attempt to decode the string with `urllib.parse.unquote(uri, encoding='utf-8', errors='replace')`
gives me

`http://joconde.givingsense.eu/onto/debug/champlitte_;_mus%c3%a9e_d%c3%a9partemental_albert_demard`

and with another pass with unquote gives me

`http://joconde.givingsense.eu/onto/debug/champlitte_;_musée_départemental_albert_demard`

which is what I expect.

The same code under Windows gives me what I expect directly with `uri = flaskrequest.url` (uri==uridec==uridecdec in the following code)

An example route in my code is

```
@app.route('/onto/debug/<id>') 
def debug(id):
    uri = flaskrequest.url
    uridec = urllib.parse.unquote(uri, encoding='utf-8', errors='replace')
    uridecdec = urllib.parse.unquote(uridec, encoding='utf-8', errors='replace')
    res = render_template("debug.html",
                          uri=uri, uridec=uridec, uridecdec=uridecdec).encode('utf-8')
    return res
```

How can I manage correctly such URL/route/chars under Linux as I do it under Windows?

Comment: What is `flaskrequest`? Are you running the dev server in both environments or is either behind a webserver like Apache?

Comment: Also, how are the requests made - through a browser, or a tool like CURL?  Are you escaping the URLs in advance or leaving it to the tool that makes the requests?

Comment: @snakecharmerb flaskrequest was obtained by `from flask import request as flaskrequest`

Comment: @snakecharmerb I'm running the dev server under windows; and my app is linked to the provider server (Apache, i suppose) via wsgi under linux

Comment: @snakecharmerb the requests are made through a brower (Chrome) without escaping myself the url

Comment: Note: URLs must be escaped (at level of HTTP). Just modern browsers unescape the URL, to show it nicer. In your case, it just seems URL get double escaped. I recommend you to add `print` statements on server code, and check the output, to find where you get the double quotes. If you do at browser part, it is much more difficult because browsers modify answers.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi but my problem isn't to display correctly the url, but t use it in my code: the url is used as an ID/key for some data in a database (in reality a knowledge graph) and the url obtained with the double unquote is wrong to use in my request although the display is correct (perhaps wrong charset)